# postgresql regex replaces the first match only

Tags: regex, postgresql

Struggling to understand how to make regexp_match string function in postgresql behave the way I want.  I have a string and I want to replace any instance of multiple spaces with just one space.  So for instance

```
'mitt     romney'
```

becomes

```
'mitt romney'
```

I believe the following code should work:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('This      is a    test', '[ ]+', ' ');
```

The expected result would be

```
'This is a test'`
```

but instead I get back

```
'This is a     test'`.
```

Its as if the replacement is only replacing the first match.  Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's bizarre, looks to me like it's documented:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

> The flags parameter is an optional text string containing zero or more
>   single-letter flags that change the function's behavior. Flag i
>   specifies case-insensitive matching, while *flag g specifies
>   replacement of each matching substring rather than only the first one*.

Emphasis, my own.

Answer (score 7):

There is a fourth optional parameter in the regexp_replace function which, when specified, resuls in the desired behavior.

If I do

```
regexp_replace('This      is    a        test`, '[ ]+', ' ', 'g')
```

I get the desired result.